# onTextChanged event in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-button

My problem is little tangled, i have to EditText boxes. Now, when i typing something on first EditText then its shows on second EditText. And as vice versa while typing on second EditText it sets on first EditText. But it gives some error on setText of any one of EditText. Below is my code,

```
Boolean flag,flag2;
txt_editText_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}
@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count)
{
if(s.length() != 0)
{
flag=true;
flag2=false;
if(flag==true)
{
String result=txt_editText_1.getText().toString().trim();
txt_editText_2.setText(""+result);
}
}
}
});

txt_editText_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}
@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count)
{
if(s.length() != 0)
{
flag=false;
flag2=true;
if(flag2==true)
{
String result=txt_editText_2.getText().toString().trim();
txt_editText_1.setText(""+result);
}
}
}
});
```

But its not working. So, can anyone give suggestion.

Comment: tell us maybe what's wrong? what do you want to happen? you didn't gave us much info about what you want to achieve

Comment: what exactly is the use of the two flags?  I would just remove them, they seem redundant/useless

Comment: But by removing that flags, it couldn't solve my problem. @chancea

Comment: What is the **exact** error you are getting?

Comment: AndroidRuntime(11979): at com.example.demoapp.Activity$2.onTextChanged(Activity.java:59) @nem

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I have put touch event on EditText for maintain flag(Boolean) status.

```
Boolean flag,flag2;
txt_editText_1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) 
{
flag=true;
flag2=false;
return true;
}
}
});

txt_editText_2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) 
{
flag=false;
flag2=true;
return true;
}
}
});

txt_editText_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}
@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count)
{
if(s.length() != 0)
{
if(flag==true)
{
String result=txt_editText_1.getText().toString().trim();
txt_editText_2.setText(""+result);
}
}
}
});

txt_editText_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}
@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count)
{
if(s.length() != 0)
{
if(flag2==true)
{
String result=txt_editText_2.getText().toString().trim();
txt_editText_1.setText(""+result);
}
}
}
});
```